# Using ddply with gsub to change multiple characters

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, gsub

I already did this manual way, but I wonder there should be a nicer way to change the info using gsub and ddply.

I have a data frame with 2 columns. The first one is the user Id, which I don't want to touch, and the second one, which is a column filled with numbers associated to activities. I want to change the number for its corresponding activity. Let's say my df is:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 3), act = rep(c(1, 2, 3), 3)
```

And the activities associated are:

```
acdf <- data.frame(num = c(1, 2, 3), actname = c("run", "walk", "fly"))
```

My actual dfs are bigger but this will work for my example. I thought of using gsub to change the number to its actual name, but I did it this way, because I'm not sure how to use ddply:

```
df$act <- gsub("1", acdf[1, 2], df$act)
df$act <- gsub("2", acdf[2, 2], df$act)
df$act <- gsub("3", acdf[3, 2], df$act)
```

My dataframe should look like this:

```
ID    act
1    run
1    walk
1    fly
2    run
2    walk
2    fly
3    run
3    walk
3    fly
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

using merge

```
merge(df, acdf, by.x='act', by.y = 'num')
```

dplyr approach

```
names(acdf)[1] <- 'act'

library(dplyr)
df%>%
  inner_join(acdf)
```

resulting in

```
Joining by: "act"
  ID act actname
#1  1   1     run
#2  1   2    walk
#3  1   3     fly
#4  2   1     run
#5  2   2    walk
#6  2   3     fly
#7  3   1     run
#8  3   2    walk
#9  3   3     fly
```

with ultra fast data.table, no need to change column names

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key = 'act')
dtacdf <- data.table(acdf, key = 'num') # original acdf

dt[dtacdf, nomatch = 0]

#   act ID actname
#1:   1  1     run
#2:   1  2     run
#3:   1  3     run
#4:   2  1    walk
#5:   2  2    walk
#6:   2  3    walk
#7:   3  1     fly
#8:   3  2     fly
#9:   3  3     fly
```

Comment: Yes, True @Alex. I've added to the answer.

Comment: I didn't thought about merge! Though it mixes all my results. Is there a way to avoid to keep them in the same order they were before?

Comment: @JPoveda you want the df with the same original order? to which method?

Comment: @PauloCardoso the merge method worked fine, except it would scramble all my ID's

Comment: @JPoveda What you mean? Isn't it a reorder of ID only?

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `match`

```
 df$act <- acdf$actname[match(df$act, acdf$num)]
 df
 #  ID  act
 #1  1  run
 #2  1 walk
 #3  1  fly
 #4  2  run
 #5  2 walk
 #6  2  fly
 #7  3  run
 #8  3 walk
 #9  3  fly
```

If you want to use `gsub`, you may try `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
 library(qdap)
```

Using a different dataset:

```
  set.seed(42)
  df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:3, each=4), act = sample(1:3, 12,replace=TRUE))

   with(acdf, mgsub(num, actname, df$act))
   #[1] "fly"  "fly"  "run"  "fly"  "walk" "walk" "fly"  "run"  "walk" "fly" 
   #[11] "walk" "fly" 

   df$act
   #[1] 3 3 1 3 2 2 3 1 2 3 2 3
```